# How to automate a certain word in Figma letter component by wrapping the next line right beside it?

Tags: automation, documents, components

I generate different instances of a certain document (a letter to be precise) several times a day (in pdf).
Only thing, I change is

1. the date
2. the addressee
3. the subject
4. a certain word in the first paragraph,
5. and a certain paragraph.

Now, the date, addressee and the subjects are very easy to customise by using **component text properties**. Also I can turn the certain paragraph on and off using **boolean property**. The certain words that I need to change are from a list, so that also can be handled by the **text variable**.
BUT, these words have different character lengths and they push the next constant characters/sentences/words out of the frame or onto the next line making the letter look really odd. I want these constant characters wrap beside the text variable. Is that possible?

❌ Not Good Example:

Lorem ipsum **Special word of variable characters**

dolor sit amet.

✅ Good Example:

Lorem ipsum **Special word of variable characters** dolor sit amet.

Also if there are easier ways of generating this document, please suggest. I must keep the design and format same.

[image]